# Excel VBA loop through specific sheets with subloop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, nested-loops

I'm trying to set up a VBA loop function that will iterate through a number of specific sheets, conducting a single nested-loop within each sheet. The nested loop is a sumif function, and I need to store this in `sumHACC` until each sheet has been looped through, with the final value (sum of each sumif) to be entered into a single cell.

The nested loop is being used on its own under a different if condition (see under `'ALL OTHER FUNDERS` at the bottom), but I'm struggling to nest this within the loop to iterate it across different sheets - The double loop is in `'IF HACC IS SELECTED`. The name of each sheet that needs to be looped through is stored in cells `D6:D19`, which I pull into `HACCRange`, and I'm trying to loop through these sheets with:

```
For Each HACC In HACCRange
Set calcTab1 = Sheets(HACC)
```

and this is where I receive a Type mismatch error. The code in this section isn't complete (i.e. no update to sumHACC) as I'm completely bamboozled as to how to make this work!

There is technically another loop on top of this (the sumif condition moves down a list (reference)), however this doesn't seem to be the problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub FunderLevel()
Dim reference As Range
Dim Funder As String
Dim itemRef1 As Range
Dim itemRef3 As Range
Dim calcTab1 As Worksheet
Dim calcTab3 As Worksheet
Dim sumCol As Range
Dim printCalc As Range
Dim HACCRange As Range
Dim QCCRange As Range

i = 21
Set reference = Range("A21:A22")
Funder = Range("A10")

'IF HACC IS SELECTED
If Funder = "HACC" Then
sumHACC = 0
Set HACCRange = Sheets("Reference Sheet").Range("D6:D19")
For Each HACC In HACCRange
    Set calcTab1 = Sheets(HACC)
    Set itemRef1 = calcTab1.Range("A10:A500") 
    myCol = calcTab1.Rows(7).Find(What:="All", LookIn:=xlValues,     LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
With calcTab1
Set sumCol = calcTab1.Range(.Cells(10, myCol), .Cells(500, myCol))
End With
For Each Cell In reference
    Set printCalc = Cells(i, 2)
    printCalc = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(itemRef1, Cell, sumCol)
    i = i + 1
Next Cell
Next HACC

'ALL OTHER FUNDERS
Else:
Set calcTab3 = Sheets(Funder)
Set itemRef3 = calcTab3.Range("A10:A500")
myCol = calcTab3.Rows(7).Find(What:="All", LookIn:=xlValues,     LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Colum
With calcTab3
Set sumCol = calcTab3.Range(.Cells(10, myCol), .Cells(500, myCol))
End With
For Each Cell In reference
    Set printCalc = Cells(i, 2)
    printCalc = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(itemRef3, Cell, sumCol)
    i = i + 1
Next Cell

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is confusing and, I suspect, overly long. I recommend that you go back to the drawing board and manually lay out (no code) your general flow algorithm. How would you expect data to flow? Does it turn out that you need to do your entire loop initially first to find values, before you can go back and use those values? Do you need to store your variables under an array instead of under a single variable? Then if that doesn't work, come back with a reduced section of code that is as small as possible while still producing your error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
For Each HACC In HACCRange.Cells
   Set calcTab1 = Sheets(HACC.value)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was exactly the error I was making. Apologies for the long/confusion question! Cheers.